# Mobli Oauth Scopes

Tags: authentication, mobli

I'm having an issue with the access token. Every token I get has a empty scope. Though in my authorize URL, I have set scopes in various combinations. I receive all the token info, but scope is always blank. Below is an example of the authorze URL & output of token.

Auth Url:

> `https://oauth.mobli.com/authorize?client_id=xxx&response_type=code&state=fa90532ac5dc926609a484b60d9d457e&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcontestis.localhost%2Fapis%2Fmobli%2Fweb%2Findex.php&scope=advanced+basic`

Token Output:

> `Array ( [access_token] => xx [token_type] => mobli_user_related [expires_in] => 7776001 [refresh_token] => xx [user] => Array ( [id] => xx13030 [username] => XX [first_name] => XX [last_name] => XX ) [scopes] => )`